# How to validate already created form using jquery , bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have login form with two field User Name and password.These fields are validated .But Now I want to change it in Registration Form by adding more fields like password and confirm password and email now how can i make sure that password entered is matched with confirm password field and similarly how to validate email field.

```
                 Login form


                 <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <section id="content1">
                    <form>
                         <div class="modal-header">
                               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                        <h1 class="modal-title">Signin Form</h1>
                              </div>

                         <div class="modal-body">


                            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" />


                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />


                             </div>


                        <div class="modal-footer" style="padding-left:86px">



                            <input type="submit" value="Log in" style="background-color:whitesmoke" />

                            </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- form -->
                </section>
                <!-- content -->
                <!-- container -->
            //</div>
```

and i added these three files.

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: MVC already has this all built in (both client and the essential server side validation) by using `ValidationAttributes` and enabling client side validation with the relevant scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For email validation, we can use regex expression:

```js
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

This will true or false on valid email address

For password validation:

```js
function ValidatePassword(){
   var password = $("#password").val();
   var confirmPassword = $("#confirm-password").val();
   if (password != confirmPassword ) {
       return false;
   } else {
       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: where i call validatepassword() function

Comment: http://www.antimath.info/js/simple-confirm-password-or-email-validation/

Try this link

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new fields for confirm password and email address.

```
<input type="password" required="" id="confirmPassword" />
<span id='message'></span>
<input type="email" required="" id="emailAddress" />
<input type="submit" value="Log in" id="submitButtonId" style="background-color:whitesmoke" />
```

If you are using HTML5, you can use the input type = "email" otherwise use this

```
pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/"
```

Then in Javascript you can validate the value of Password and confirm password field as:

```
var password = $("#password").val();
   var confirmPassword = $("#confirmPassword").val();
   if (password != confirmPassword ) {
       $('#message').html('Matching');
       $('#submitButtonId').prop('disabled', false);
   } else {
       $('#message').html('Not Matching');
       $('#submitButtonId').prop('disabled', true);
   }
```

**If, you want to do it before submitting**, you can use the following code:

```
$('#password, #confirmPassword').on('keyup', function () {
  if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirmPassword').val()) {
    $('#message').html('Matching').css('color', 'green');
    $('#submitButtonId').prop('disabled', false);
  } else{ 
    $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
    $('#submitButtonId').prop('disabled', true);
  }
```

});

Comment: Do you have a JavaScript file where you are doing any operations ? If yes, then you can create a method there otherwise you can write it in html also using <script type="text/javascript"> tag

Comment: I mean i have to call this function on submit button click or any other place..I have added above function in scripts tags

Comment: Yes, you can call it onSubmit and then inside this method when password == confirmPassword, you can call your other method for any ajax calls or something

Comment: @waleed If it is solved, can you please mark it solved with the correct answer ?

Comment: My issue is that i have already validated login form with two fields name and password. now i change it in registration form which required more field like confirm password, address etc  so i want to validate is password is matched with password entered before submitting the form which is not working by using the above function as i submit data by entering mismatched password it is still submitting and not giving me error of password mismatchd

Comment: Then you should be clear, that you want it before submitting the form. I will edit my answer. Please check that for before submitting.

Comment: @waleed please test it and let me know

Comment: it is still submitting the form whether Password Not matched or matched.

Comment: Then we can disable the button, if the password is not matching. I have updated the code, please test and tell me

Answer (score 0):

Since JQuery is already a requirement of Bootstrap you could use the following validation plugin to validate the password fields: https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/

You could use a code like this to validate the passwords

```
    <!-- New password row -->
<div class="form-inline row">

    <!-- 50% -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">

        <!-- First password input field with custom minlength attribute -->
        <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"
               required>

        <!-- Block with requirement -->
        <div class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</div>
    </div>
    <!-- 50% -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">

        <!-- Input field with custom error message when passwords don't match -->
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordConfirm" data-match="#password"
               data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>

        <!-- Block to show error message -->
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will need to add an ID attribute to the form and activate the validator plugin.

```
$('#myForm').validator();
```

Keep in mind that you never need to rely on JavaScript **only** and it's always a must to validate the password server-side.